# Transformation of variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Two independent random variables $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ have the same uniform distribution on interval $[0,1]$. What is the distribution of variable $Y_{1}=X^{2}_{1}+X^{2}_{2}$ and $Y_{2}=X_{1}X_{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation $H$ is not injective, since you have the symmetry: $H(x_1,x_2) = H(x_2,x_1)$.  The transformation is injective on the region
below or above the diagonal.  Restrict to one of those and then multiply the density by $2$.

The domain for $(Y_1, Y_2)$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the straight lines
$Y_2 = Y_1/2$ and $Y_2 = 0$ and the parabola $Y_1 = 1 + Y_2^2$.